# Open SWF file within browser from a tag?

Tags: html, flash

I want to be able to open a .swf file within the browser by just clicking a link, eg:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/myswf.swf">Link</a>
```

But currently clicking this link does nothing. If I right click it and select 'Open in New Tab' the .swf just downloads.

Does anyone know a way I can just open a new page/tab and play the file within the browser?

Comment: The easiest would be having a rudimentary HTML page that embeds the player and accepts the SWF's file name as an argument

Comment: Could it be the mime type sent with the file or the fact that your browser may not have an swf plugin?